# Minify / compress JS and CSS by Server?

Tags: apache, compression

my webpage is running on an Apache Server, because of big CSS and JS files I want to minify/compress the files like this:

If the CSS/JS file is changed, the Server should that that changed file, compress it and save it as a new file?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gulp https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md it can minify automatically anytime you modify your styles.

Comment: Ok thanks and how do I add the files that needs to be compressed and tell how to save it as a new file?